# Change delimiter in a CSV file

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv, replace

I have an input file in CSV format. There are some fields enclosed in double quotes that have a comma in them. Here is the sample row

```
123,"ABC, DEV 23",345,534.202,NAME
```

I need to remove all the commas that are not occurring within the double quotes by a `~`,
so the output should be like this:

```
123~"ABC, DEV 23"~345~534.202~NAME
```

I have tried this, but it gives me the reverse output:

```
awk -F '"' -v OFS='' '{ for (i=0; i<= NF; ++i) gsub(",","~",$i) } 1' test.txt
123,ABC~ DEV 23,345,534.202,NAME
```

Comment: You will very unlikely have an answer. Best pratice  on stack exchange is to show some work and some of your try. You should consult https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour You can edit your question to show what you've try so far.

Answer (score 7):

You basically have a CSV file that you would like to replace the delimiter in, from `,` to `~`.

Using [`csvkit`](http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/):

```
$ csvformat -D '~' file.csv >newfile.csv

$ cat newfile.csv
123~ABC, DEV 23~345~534.202~NAME
```

`cvsformat` removes the quotation marks that are not needed.  To *add* quotation marks:

```
$ csvformat -U 1 -D '~' file.csv
"123"~"ABC, DEV 23"~"345"~"534.202"~"NAME"
```

See `csvformat --help` for usage info.

---

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) instead:

```bash
$ mlr --csv -N --ofs '~' cat file.csv
123~ABC, DEV 23~345~534.202~NAME
```

Retaining the original quotes even though they are no longer needed:

```bash
$ mlr --csv -N --ofs '~' --quote-original cat file.csv
123~"ABC, DEV 23"~345~534.202~NAME
```

In both of these commands, the `-N` option is use to signal the fact that the input has no header and that the output shouldn't have one either.  The `--ofs` option sets the output field separator.

Answer (score 1):

GNU **`awk`** solution:

```
awk -v FPAT='[^,]+|"[^"]+"' '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s%s",$i,(i<NF? "~" : ORS) }' file
```

- `FPAT='[^,]+|"[^"]+"'` - regex pattern describing each field is either *“anything that is not a comma,”* or *“a double quote, anything that is not a double quote, and a closing double quote.”*

The output:

```
123~"ABC, DEV 23"~345~534.202~NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this awk

```
awk 'NR%2==1{gsub(",","~")}1' RS='"' ORS='"' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -MText::CSV -e 'csv(in => csv(in => $*IN), out => $*OUT, sep => "~");' < Adhya.csv
```

Sample Input:

```
123,"ABC, DEV 23",345,534.202,NAME
```

Sample Output:

```
123~"ABC, DEV 23"~345~534.202~NAME
```

This answer uses the Raku Programming Language. The Perl(5) module `Text::CSV_XS` is well-regarded, and a longtime author/maintainer of that module has gone on to develop Raku's `Text::CSV` module (H. Merijn Brand, personal communication).

Briefly, the high-level `csv(...)` command is used to take csv input via `$*IN` (stdin). Alternative `sep`arators can be specified here with `sep => "\t"` or similar.

Then, the output is send via `$*OUT` (stdout), changing the `sep`arator to `~` tilde with the parameter `sep => "~"`.

https://github.com/Tux/CSV/blob/master/doc/Text-CSV.md
https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

I have done by below 2 methods for above example . Tested

Method1

```
for (( i=1;i<6;i++)); do awk -F "," -v i="$i" '$i ~ /"/{gsub(" ",",",$2);print }' inputfile;done| tail -1| sed 's/,/~/3g'| sed 's/,/~/1'
```

output

```
123~"ABC, DEV 23"~345~534.202~NAME'
```

Method2

```
 sed "s/,/~/3g" inputfile| sed 's/,/~/1'
```

Output

```
123~"ABC, DEV 23"~345~534.202~NAME'
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to install a special package, you can probably the csv parser of a preinstalled ruby:

```
ruby -e 'require "csv"; CSV.filter(output_col_sep: "~") {}'
```

Examples:

```
1,"2,3"
```

results in

```
1~2,3
```

and

```
1,"
2,3
",4
```

results in

```
1~"
2,3
"~4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sub(/,/,"~")gsub(/,/,"~",$3)}1' file

output
123~"ABC, DEV 23"~345~534.202~NAME
```

The very first comma is replaced by sub and the rest by gsub in third field.

Comment: The code may provide answer to the question, but any explanations will be highly appretiated