# I have a csv file with a field having data enclosed in " " and commas in between. I want to replace it with another

Tags: text-processing, text-formatting

Below is the first 5 lines of my file. Here, I want to replace the "10,00,000.0" of 5th column with "10,000,000.0".

```
DE000A2200V7,09:30:00,8.5,8.509,"10,00,000.0","10,00,000.0","850,450.0"
DE000A2200V7,11:30:00,8.7,8.709,"20,00,000.0","20,000.0","870,450.0"
DE000A2200V7,13:30:00,8.763,8.883,"30,00,000.0","20,000.0","882,300.0"
DE000A2200V7,15:30:00,8.481,8.501,"10,00,000.0","10,00,000.0","849,100.0"
DE000A2200W5,09:30:00,15.826,15.835,"20,000.0","20,000.0","1,583,050.0"
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Do I understand you correctly that you want to replace the erroneous `n,00,000.0` with `n,000,000.0` in all occurences in the 5th column? Do you also want to do that in the 6th column?

Comment: Surely should it be multiplied by 10, instead of just changing the commas to mark thousands and millions?

Answer (score 1):

By temporarily changing the CSV delimiter to a `@` (or any other character that is not already part of the data) using `csvformat` from [`csvkit`](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), then changing the relevant strings in the 5th field with `awk`, and returning the delimiter to the original comma:

```sh
csvformat -D '@' data.csv |
awk 'BEGIN { OFS=FS="@" } $5 == "10,00,000.0" { $5 = "10,000,000.0" }; 1' |
csvformat -d '@'
```

With your data in `data.csv`, this produces:

```
DE000A2200V7,09:30:00,8.5,8.509,"10,000,000.0","10,00,000.0","850,450.0"
DE000A2200V7,11:30:00,8.7,8.709,"20,00,000.0","20,000.0","870,450.0"
DE000A2200V7,13:30:00,8.763,8.883,"30,00,000.0","20,000.0","882,300.0"
DE000A2200V7,15:30:00,8.481,8.501,"10,000,000.0","10,00,000.0","849,100.0"
DE000A2200W5,09:30:00,15.826,15.835,"20,000.0","20,000.0","1,583,050.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `awk`

```
awk -vFPAT='([^,]*)|("[^"]+")' -vOFS=, '$5 == "\"10,00,000.0\"" \
{ $5="\"10,000,000.0\""}; {print}' file
```

Tests

```
$ cat file
DE000A2200V7,09:30:00,8.5,8.509,"10,00,000.0","10,00,000.0","850,450.0"
DE000A2200V7,11:30:00,8.7,8.709,"20,00,000.0","20,000.0","870,450.0"
DE000A2200V7,13:30:00,8.763,8.883,"30,00,000.0","20,000.0","882,300.0"
DE000A2200V7,15:30:00,8.481,8.501,"10,00,000.0","10,00,000.0","849,100.0"
DE000A2200W5,09:30:00,15.826,15.835,"20,000.0","20,000.0","1,583,050.0"

$ awk -vFPAT='([^,]*)|("[^"]+")' -vOFS=, '$5 == "\"10,00,000.0\"" { $5="\"10,000,000.0\""}; {print}' file
DE000A2200V7,09:30:00,8.5,8.509,10,000,000.0,"10,00,000.0","850,450.0"
DE000A2200V7,11:30:00,8.7,8.709,"20,00,000.0","20,000.0","870,450.0"
DE000A2200V7,13:30:00,8.763,8.883,"30,00,000.0","20,000.0","882,300.0"
DE000A2200V7,15:30:00,8.481,8.501,10,000,000.0,"10,00,000.0","849,100.0"
DE000A2200W5,09:30:00,15.826,15.835,"20,000.0","20,000.0","1,583,050.0"
```

Explanation

```
-vFPAT='([^,]*)|("[^"]+")'
```

separates the fields by commas, handling the cases where the fields may contain embedded commas (see GNU awk manual [Defining Fields by Content](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Splitting-By-Content)).

```
-vOFS=,
```

states that the output file separator is the comma `,`.

```
'$5 == "\"10,00,000.0\"" { $5="\"10,000,000.0\""}; {print}'
```

if fifth column matches the string "10,00,000.0" replace it by "10,000,000.0"; print the line.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with following `sed` command:

```
sed -i 's/^\(\([^,]*,\)\{4\}\)\("[^"]*"\)\(.*\)$/\1"10,000,000.0"\4/' data.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure that "20,00,000.0" is correct? If not, try

```
sed 's/,00,/,000,/' file
```

Add `s`'s `g` flag if all wrong number should be cured...

Answer (score 0):

Just break and reconstruct the lines on `"` by setting `FS=OFS="\""` and test the 2nd field

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\""} $2=="10,00,000.0"{$2="10,000,000.0"};1' file1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case the real question is:

> How do the change to commas from grouping [thousand, lakh and crore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system#Use_of_separators) to grouping by thousands, millions, etc in the *fields* of a CSV file?

maybe this will do, extending upon the same trick from another [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/571697/308316):

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 awk -v RS='"' -v ORS= '{
  if(NR % 2){print}
  else if(/[^0-9.,]/){print RS $0 RS}
  else { gsub(/,/,""); printf RS "%'\''.1f" RS, $0}
}' file

DE000A2200V7,09:30:00,8.5,8.509,"1,000,000.0","1,000,000.0","850,450.0"
DE000A2200V7,11:30:00,8.7,8.709,"2,000,000.0","20,000.0","870,450.0"
DE000A2200V7,13:30:00,8.763,8.883,"3,000,000.0","20,000.0","882,300.0"
DE000A2200V7,15:30:00,8.481,8.501,"1,000,000.0","1,000,000.0","849,100.0"
DE000A2200W5,09:30:00,15.826,15.835,"20,000.0","20,000.0","1,583,050.0"
```

This assumes an awk with locale support or which doesn't implement itself `printf` (`gawk`, `bwk`, Thomas Dickey's `mawk`). The default awk from Debian (an old version of `mawk`) will NOT do.

Only `LC_NUMERIC` is needed; `LC_ALL` is used as a cure against another `LC_ALL` that may be present in the environment ;-)

Answer (score -1):

`sed -i.backup 's/,"10,00,000.0"/,"10,000,000.0"/' data.csv`

1. `-i.backup` write result to original file and backup original data to data.csv.backup
2. `s/` search `,""10,00,000.0"` and replace `/,"10,000,000.0"/`only first match in string
3. `data.csv` file to proceed

Comment: It would be easy to change the 6th column by mistake, for example if the second to last line had said `20,00,000.0` in the 5th column.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please, don't attach screenshots of console commands/console output; they can be difficult to read and (in particular when used in a question) make it difficult for contributors to reproduce the commands you typed. Instead, copy-and-paste it into your answer with appropriate formatting.